# How to shift columns in a matrix to the right in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix

[Given the following Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wauad.jpg): How can I achieve this? I am trying to shift the columns to the right, but I can only get them to shift to the left. I also cannot account for the column on the end being shifted to the front. I know I need to use some kind of temporary array, but I don't know how to implement it.

My code so far:

```
function [B] = column_shift()

A = input('Enter an nx6 matrix: ')
interimA = A(:,6);
    for n = 1:5
        A(:,n) = A(:,n+1);
        interimA = A(:,1);

    end
B = A
end
```

Comment: You assignments inside the loop are backwards. The variable on the left of the `=` is given the value of the thing on the right.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use `circshift`:

```
%# shift by 1 along dimension 2
shiftedA = circshift(A,1,2);
```

Note: [CIRCSHIFT](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/circshift.html?refresh=true) has changed its definition. Earlier versions of Matlab only took one input argument, so you'd have to write `circshift(A,[0,1])` (shift 0 along first, 1 along second dimension) to achieve the same result as above.

If you absolutely do need to use a for-loop, you can do the following:

```
shiftStep = 1;
%# create an index array with the shifted column indices
nCols = size(A,2);
shiftedIndices = circshift(1:nCols,shiftStep,2);

shiftedA = A; %# initialize the output to the same size as the input

%# for-loop could be replaced by shiftedA = A(:,shiftedIndices);
for iCol = 1:nCols
    shiftedA(:,iCol) = A(:,iCol==shiftedIndices);
end
```

Comment: I would use circshift, but the problem states that I need to use a for loop.

Comment: @user3006937, would you be surprised if I told you that it's useful to include your full problem specification in your question? Note that "linking the full question in an image file" is not useful in any way.

Comment: @user3006937 so just use `for ii = 42; shiftedA = circshift(A,1,2); end` - you could include a message `disp(' Dear Mr. supervisor I don't need  and shouldn't use a loop here!)` ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've made a modified and commented version of your code. Hope it helps!
Just a few notes:

You were shifting the columns to the left because you were shifting with column n+1, when you should be shifting with n-1.

The column in the end is a special case that is handled before the for loop (if you really need to do everything inside a for loop, you can start the cycle on n = 1, check if the loop is in the first column, and handled that "special shift" there).

You don't really need the temporary array. You can create one if it helps you make the code more understandable, but in this case I haven't used one.

```
function [B] = column_shift()

A = input('Enter an nx6 matrix: ')
B = A;
B(:,1) = A(:,end);              %copy the last column of A to the first column of B
    for n = 2 : size(A,2)       %starting on the second column of A, until the last column...
        B(:,n) = A(:,n-1);      %copy the column "n-1" on A to the column "n" in B
    end
end
```